# Phonegap open pdf with default reader (IOS and Android)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

My question is if there is a way to open a previously downloaded PDF (I have this part done) with the default mobile pdf reader or even better, a pop-up shows and ask what pdf reader you want to open the file.

I tried ChildBrowser and it works, but I need another pdf reader.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FileOpener plugin](https://github.com/jwark/FileOpener/tree/cordova-3.0)

This version works for both, iOS and android

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this plugin before but did not get it to work in IOs

Comment: Can you give more details and not just a "did not get it to work"? Post some code and some relevant error or console log